# Assigning a value to a variable

Tags: ruby, variables, size

I would like the variable `size` to be defined in my program via user input. I have been unsuccessful in defining it in any way other than by a number manually entered into my code (currently `10`).

```
def pass (size = 10)
```

Comment: You want to make a integer a part of your  object? or you just want to assign a value to an already existing internal var?

Comment: What do you mean "unsuccessful" - did you get an error? what exactly did you try? ( I assume you tried 'gets', which returns string, .to_i  converts it to integer).  Anyway, please provide more relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
def pass(size)
    puts size
end

puts "please input a number:"
size = gets
pass(size)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use to_i, as your user input is a string. Then it works as the previous answer:

```
def pass(size = 10)
  size = size.to_i
  puts "It's a number! #{size}" if size.is_a? Integer
end

puts "please input a number:"
size = gets
pass(size)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem 100% correct: first you convert size to integer, then check if it's indeed an integer?

Comment: This is just a simple example showing that it is indeed an integer now. If you remove the previous line, it won't work.

Comment: Yes, anyway, then what's point of checking if it's an Integer, after making sure it is indeed an Integer? You're basically testing the .to_i method in the second line. IOW, it seems equivalent to: "puts "It's a number! #{size}" if true"

Comment: code-wise yes, but as the question author said himself he's new to Ruby, I'm making a point as to why you need to call `.to_i`. I can remove the extra line if you really think it's unnecessary.